# Any Risks in Using Signin With Google plus

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm building a web application and have decided to allow users to signin with google plus, using the client side api.

Now, I'm wondering how secure this is, because i had to provide a callback function which will be called after the button is loaded.

I wonder if a user can edit this function and manipulate what happens after signup.
Also, are there recommended ways to ensure security when using such signin services?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining your own secure sign-in system is not trivial. When you rely on Google as your identity provider you have Google engineers who are the best in the world and deal keeping  hundreds of millions of accounts secure against some of the most aggressive, intelligent and motivated hackers who have tremendous resources behind them. You can trust that they will do a better job than you against these threats.

Now, you are right at looking at that handoff from Google to your site as a potential point for needing to do additional checking. The successful callback that comes to your site should include an access token (and one-time authorization code in the hybrid server-side flow). You could immediately perform an API request using that token to verify that the token is legit and not forged. In fact, many sites do an immediate [request for the user's profile data](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information) to populate their user's record with name, picture, email etc.

If that token results in an access denied failure from the API, something is up and you shouldn't trust the callback.

You can also verify ID tokens that are returned. The ID tokens are cryptographically signed to ensure that they have not been tampered. This is a more complicated process and useful when you need to send tokens from your client to a back-end so that your backend can verify that the tokens came from a real user AND from your specific client. See [Tim Bray's post on ID tokens for more info](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2013/04/04/ID-Tokens).